# Compare two similar columns from two tables in SQL Server C# Windows App

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

I am working on a quiz app with multiple choices.

I have two tables.

1. Questions - it has a column named CorrectAnswer
2. UserQuestions - it has a column named SelectedAnswer

I want to check if the CorrectAnswer in the first table is equal to the SelectedAnswer in the second table, both tables have userId and QuestionText columns

This is meant to calculate the score.
The output I am expecting is a number after comparing it.

The solution I have tried implementing so far is querying both tables

```
SELECT UserId, QuestionText, CorrectAnswer FROM Questions
```

```
SELECT UserId, QuestionText, SelectedAnswer FROM UserQuestions
```

Save all the values in an array of dictionary, then try comparing them if they are equal I set the count variable then save the score.

I am hoping if there's a much better approach.

Comment: inner join and count?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  How do you handle users who don't answer a question?

Answer (score 0):

You can compute the score of each user with a join and conditional aggregation:

```
select uq.userid, 
    avg(case when uq.selectedanswer = q.correctanswer then 1.0 else 0 end) as ratio
from userquestions uq
inner join questions q 
    on  q.questiontext = ua.questiontext
    and q.userid = uq.userid
```

This gives you the ratio of correct answers per user, as a number between `0` and `1`. If you want a count of correct answers, then you can just `sum()` instead.